# How to replace Disposable with Observable

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, observer-pattern

I'm a newbie at RxJava.

One of the first things I learned is that the Observer Pattern consists of two components(among others): **Observables** and **Observers**

In the code below what is the Observable and what is the Observer?

```
class JsonRepository{

private val client by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
        .build()
        .create(JsonApi::class.java)
}

var disposable: Disposable? = null
var allArticles: List<Article> = emptyList()


fun loadJson(){
    disposable = client.getAllArticles()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { result -> allArticles = result },
            { error -> Log.e("ERROR", error.message) }
        )
}

}
```

Also, how can I change my code so I can use Observable or Flowable instead of Disposable

Answer (score 1):

## Observable

Check what is returned by all things in the chain `client.getAllArticles()`, `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`. Every single of those three calls return an `Observable` (before or after some sort of transformation).

The last one in the chain (the result of `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`) is the eventual `Observable` that is used by you.

[image: Observable]

*It's the thing that will be observed by the `Observer`.*

---

## Observer

From [RxJava docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html):

> The Subscribe method is how you connect an observer to an Observable. Your observer implements some subset of the following methods:
>
> onNext [...]
>
> onError [...]
>
> onCompleted [...]

[image]

---

## Question

> Also, how can I change my code so I can use Observable or Flowable instead of Disposable

Usually you would just expose an `Observable` and let the "user" of the Repository create an `Observer` and manage the `Disposable` (the hook for taking record of subscribed `Observers`). So something like this (not tested, writing off the top of my head):

```
fun loadJson() : Observable<Article> = client.getAllArticles().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

(`observeOn` is really for the `Observer`)